# The orbits of an algebraic action of a semidirect product of a unipotent group and a compact group are closed?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

We consider real algebraic groups and real algebraic varieties. It is known that the orbits of an algebraic action of a unipotent algebraic group $U$ on an affine variety are closed. The orbits of an algebraic action of a compact Lie group $K$ (which always has a canonical structure of an algebraic group) are also  closed.

> **Question.** Let $G$ be a  semidirect product $U\rtimes K$ of a unipotent group $U$ and compact group $K$. Is it true that the orbits of $G$ on an affine variety are closed?

Comment: When considering orbits, do you consider the orbits in the  $\Bbb C$-points or in the  $\Bbb R$-points? Also, when writing "closed", what topology do you consider?

Comment: 3

"We consider real algebraic groups and real algebraic varieties" - so \bf R points! Closed - in any of two topologies (Zariski or Euclidean)

Answer (score 5):

The groups in question were considered in my joint paper with Bernhard Krötz entitled [Reductive group actions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.01005) under the name "quasi-anisotropic groups". By definition, these are the connected linear algebraic groups $G$ over a field $K$ such that every unipotent element of $G(K)$ sits in the unipotent radical of $G$. Over $\mathbb R$ or any perfect field these are just the semidirect products of an anisotropic group by an unipotent group.

We proved (loc. cit. Cor. 3.9): Let $G$ be a quasi-anisotropic group acting on a quasi-affine variety $X$, everything defined over a perfect
field $K$. Then the orbit $Gx$ where $x\in X(K)$ is (Zariski-)closed in $X$.

Over $\mathbb R$ this immediately implies that $G(\mathbb R)x$ is Hausdorff-closed in $X(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer and for the link to the publication with the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

As $K$ is compact, the second coordinate projection map $K\times V \to V$ is closed (here $V$ is the ambient variety). Precomposing this map with the homeomorphism $K\times V \to K\times V$, $(k,v)\mapsto (k,kv)$, you get the action map $K\times V \to V$, which is thus closed. For $x\in V$, the orbit $Gx$ is the action map image of the closed subset $K\times Ux \subset K\times V$, so it is closed in $V$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I think I understand your arguments. I had confidence that my assumption was correct, as well as some thoughts on how to prove it. But your reasoning has completely exhausted my doubts.